# how to understand the gradient vector flow formula

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

Currently, I am learning [gradient vector flow](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ejsatta/statvis/project.pdf). I have one question about the calculation.

After Euler equations, the GVF can be found by solving the following formula:

[image]

Then, the paper said: "Equations (8) and (9) can be solved numerically by treating u and v as a function of time." The resulting equations are

[image]

I have no idea how to obtain equation (10) from equation (8). Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

Comment: Equation 10 *is* equation 8, where you replace 0 with $u_t = \partial u / \partial t$. At the steady state, u doesn't change any more, so you get back to (8). You have then found u.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. I don't understand `u does't change any more, so you get back to (8)`. If u does't change any more, u is a constant $u=C$. But if u=C, equation (8) may be wrong because $\nabla^2 u=0 $, but $(u-f_x)(f_x^2 + f_y^2)$ is not equal to 0. Could you please give me more details?

Comment: This is an iterative optimization algorithm. u(t) is initialized for t=0, then you compute du/dt, which tells you how to update u to produce u(1), rinse and repeat until du/dt is small enough. u(t+1) = u(t) + du/dt(t).

Comment: Here’s code I write long ago for GVF: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/dipimage/gvf.m

Comment: I can understand the iteration workflow. The thing I don't understand is that why $u_t=\nabla^2 u-(u-f_x)(f_x^2 + f_y^2)$ would result in $\nabla^2 u-(u-f_x)(f_x^2 + f_y^2)=0$

Comment: I think I may understand it. Let $u_t=\mu \nabla^2 u-(u-f_x)(f_x^2 + f_y^2)$, after iterative optimization and u is steady, $u_t=0$. In this way, $\mu \nabla^2 u-(u-f_x)(f_x^2 + f_y^2) = u_t = 0$. Am I correct? But, how to make sure u can reach a steady state? What if  $u_t=\mu \nabla^2 u-(u-f_x)(f_x^2 + f_y^2)$ is not-convergence?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I'm not sure, but I think it converges by definition. You might get a detailed proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly reply.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, You basically solved the question. Just copy the comments into an answer :-).

Comment: @royi I usually need a lot more time to write an answer than to write a comment. I think if were to write an answer here I’d first spend half an hour looking stuff up to make sure I’m not writing incorrect information, and it would end up being a lot longer post than that comment. I’m a bit of a perfectionist that way…

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I see. Well, You can always right "I think..." :-).